# Draw Line Graph using Paint Component

Tags: java, graph, paint, paintcomponent

How would you go about creating a line graph using outputs from a thread, the threads are simulations of incoming and outgoing bill that run over a course of 52 seconds and this will be dipicted on a line graph as shown below

I want to use the paint component not any third party classes like JChart.

[image]

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Very simply put, you can use the `drawLine` method of `Graphics` in your `paint(Graphics g)` method to add a line to your graph with each iteration of your visualisation loop: `g.drawLine(prevX, prevY, x, y);` where x is the position of your graph origin on the canvas plus the x value for your graph and the same for y.

Comment: from the textfields you can add any integer for example if I add 10,000 to one of the outgoing amounts how does the panel know where the 10,000 point is in the axis

Comment: Give your axes fixed lengths in pixels and set a maximum value that they can go up to. You can then convert between axes measurements and canvas measurements by using something like `xpos = (realx/max)*length`, where real `x` is your 10000 point and `xpos` is the actual position on the canvas (without adding offsets for the graph origin).

Comment: The axis are just painted lines i am not using any graph classes just the paint method, can you still ste the axis to fixed lengths?

Comment: You should use a field in your JPanel subclass to store the length the axes should be. I'll write out an answer with a bit more information since we seem to be on the same wavelength now :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some `JPanel` object that you are using to paint on, I would add the following to your object:

```
public class GraphPanel extends JPanel{
    //static constants for defining the size and positioning of the graph on canvas
    //Ignore the values I chose, they were completely random :p
    private static final int X_AXIS_LENGTH = 1000;
    private static final int Y_AXIS_LENGTH = 500;

    private static final int X_AXIS_OFFEST = 50;
    private static final int Y_AXIS_OFFSET = 50;
...
```

These should all be constant values that define the size you want your graph to be on the canvas (the axis lengths) and its positioning (the offsets).

You can then refer to these values in the `paintComponent` method to find the actual position of the line you want to draw for this update on the canvas.

```
...
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    int x, y;
    int prevX, prevY;
    int maxX, maxY;
    ...
    //retrieve values from your model for the declared variables
    ...
    //calculate the coords of your line on the canvas
    int xPos = ((x / maxX) * X_AXIS_LENGTH) + X_AXIS_OFFSET;
    ...
    //do the same for y, prevX, prevY and then you can use g.drawLine
}
...
```

Note that you want to change `maxX` and `maxY` because the `x` and `y` values are moving above those limits, you will need to add some extra code to check for that change and redraw the whole graph with the new limits in place.

Comment: Great ive got the hang of it but i cant seem to get the correct calculation for the yPos. this is what i have been trying


double balance = (((double)y / maxY) * Y_AXIS_LENGTH - (Y_AXIS_LENGTH - Y_AXIS_OFFSET)) ;

Comment: Why are you doing `- (Y_AXIS_LENGTH - Y_AXIS_OFFSET)`? The calculation will be the same as for the X axis, you're just using y axis values for everything.

Comment: Ive got it its.........
double balance = 365 - ((((double)y / maxY) * Y_AXIS_LENGTH) + Y_AXIS_OFFSET);

Comment: Whats with the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) 365? Always assign any sort of constant to at least a final variable like I did with `X_AXIS_LENGTH`, `X_AXIS_OFFEST` etc. Then at least you can refer to one variable wherever you use that constant AND you will know what that constant is for in the future.

Comment: As I said in a comment in one of your other questions, it looks like `Y_AXIS_OFFSET` is set incorrectly. Judging from what you had to do, the correct value should probably be 365 minus your current `Y_AXIS_OFFSET` value.